# Same TableView in multiple locations swift 3

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

In my current app I have a tableview that I would like to display on multiple view controllers, I know I could copy and paste the code from one view controller to another but I know enough about coding techniques that copying and pasting large sections of code is bad practice but not enough to know a way to avoid it in this current situation. I am using swift 3 and a standard table view. Does anybody have any good suggestions for me?

Comment: Hey, could you provide more info about table view implementation? I mean whether you create it in a storyboard or entirely from code, what are dependencies, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using interface builder, you can create a view controller with only your tableview in it and "embed" it in other view controllers using a container view.

IB will create a new embedded view controller when you add the container view but you can delete that and relink the container view to the one containing you tabelview.